# Send single worksheet from workbook as an attachment to outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to send a single worksheet from workbook as an attachment by outlook. i am trying to do this but the file is not attaching to email

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()

Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

 Worksheets("RFI LOG").Copy

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook

 Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

  FileName = WB.Worksheets("new").Name

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\" & FileName
    On Error GoTo 0
    WB.SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format

    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
    '    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    '        .Cells.Copy
    '        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '        .Cells(1).Select
    '    End With
    '    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "sachin.yard@osco.com.om"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Daily RFI LOG"
            .Body = "FYINA"
            .Attachments.Add WB.Worksheets("new").Name.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` - do you get an error then? if so, what is it and on what line?

Comment: run time error 9 subscript out of range

Comment: a new workbook is created but it is not going ahead and attaching to outlook

Comment: and on which line does the error occur?

Comment: wb.SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName

Comment: and what is the value of `Filename`? does it have any characters that are not allowed in a filename? Also, you may want to save it to a folder other than the root folder as some operating systems do not allow that without special permissions.

Comment: file name will be RFI LOG ..when is convert the same file in PDF it gets attached to email but when it is xlsm it doesnt

Comment: can u come on live on teamviewer or anydesk or share ur contact details of whatsapp ..as its urgent